# Simple C++11 hash function won't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

The following code for a simple hash function won't compile

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>

namespace {
    struct Foo {
        long i;
    };
}

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<::Foo> {
        size_t operator()(::Foo foo) const {
            return hash<decltype(foo.i)>(foo.i);
        }
    };
}
```

My 4.8.5 g++ compiler emits these messages:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp
a.cpp: In member function ‘std::size_t std::hash<{anonymous}::Foo>::operator()({anonymous}::Foo) const’:
a.cpp:13:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::hash<long int>::hash(long int&)’
             return hash<decltype(foo.i)>(foo.i);
                                               ^
a.cpp:13:47: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:3033:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:55,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note: constexpr std::hash<long int>::hash()
   _Cxx_hashtable_define_trivial_hash(long)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note: constexpr std::hash<long int>::hash(const std::hash<long int>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long int’ to ‘const std::hash<long int>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note: constexpr std::hash<long int>::hash(std::hash<long int>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/functional_hash.h:107:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long int’ to ‘std::hash<long int>&&’
$ fg
```

The problem appears to be the call-by-reference in the first error message but  I don't understand why or how to fix it.

Comment: FYI, `namespace std {};` invokes undefined behavior. You aren't supposed to extend namespace std.

Comment: @Chipster Not quite. "A program may add a template specialization
for any standard library template to `namespace std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
prohibited."

Comment: @Chipster In this case it is legal.  You are allowed to open up the namespace and add specializations for your types.  see: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#1

Comment: @Brian, but adding something else is undefined behavior, other than templates.

Comment: @Chipster But the OP is doing precisely the legal thing: adding a specialisation of a standard template for their own type. This is *the* way to mesh your types with `std::hash`.

Comment: Hint: `hash<decltype(foo.i)>(foo.i)` calls the constructor of `hash<decltype(foo.i)>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a set of parentheses in

```
return hash<decltype(foo.i)>(foo.i);
```

In the above you are trying to construct a `std::hash`, not call its `operator()`.  You need

```
return hash<decltype(foo.i)>()(foo.i);
// or
return hash<decltype(foo.i)>{}(foo.i);
```

where the empty set of parentheses/curly braces constructs the hash object, and the second set calls its `operator()`

Comment: Thanks! I would not have thought of that.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson No problem.  It's an easy mistake to make when starting to work with functors.

Comment: Is the functor constructed every time? If so, is that inefficient? If so, is there a more efficient idiom?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson Yes, the hash object is constructed every time but unless it has state, then it is non-op.  I believe the default library ones are stateless and this is the common convention.  Normally you'll never notice a performance hit.  If your concerned, you could profile it but it should be fine.